# force webform to reload or start from page1 with rules

Tags: rules, webforms, forms

If for example a field 'start over' is selected, I would like to reload the webform from page 1.  Wondering the best way to do this.  I already have rules and webform validation enabled.  Do I create a custom rule?  Standard rules do not have a redirect url that I can see. Or is there a function to call to start over.

Answer (score 0):

While adding rule action you can select `System > page redirect`

[image]

This is how you can choose:

[image]

Thanks!